# Not able to browse any page connected via a wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using a tplink modem tl-wr740n. I configured my wifi router successfully and I am able to connect to it using my mobile. I can use the messenger application on my mobile but I cannot browse webpages on both my mobile and my computer.

When I connect my computer directly to the modem (bypassing the wireless router) it all works great.

Please help!

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. I would edit it to help improve it, but I'm not sure where some sentences end. Can you please [edit] this so it's not one long sentence?

Comment: editing done...

Comment: are you able to ping these websites?  if not post the result of a ping command

Comment: no i am not able to ping any website.i am only able to ping this address 192.168.1.1

Comment: currently i have connect my lan wire directly to my computer so i am able to browse all the website ...but if i connect the lan wire to my router i am not able to browse any of the websites

Comment: Have you restarted your modem after connecting the router to it? Most cable modems 'remember' the first mac address that reaches them from the inside interface and block traffic from any other device.

Comment: i have restarted 40 or more times

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your computer to the modem directly.  It that doesn't work, you may have a problem with the modem.

If it DOES work, you aren't connecting the modem to your router properly.

Comment: router is connected properly...i av checked the router in the company its fine...when i connect with the router internet light led flashes also the internet works in mobile when connected with the router but only my messenger application works...but only i cannot browse the page in my mobile and computer